# Windows 8 Audio Changes Default Playback Device or Stops Playing Audio

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, drivers

I have a Sony Vaio SVT15115CXS laptop running Windows 8 64-bit. I've recently noticed a strange audio issue. At seemingly random times, the audio may switch from the default playback device (laptop speakers) to the second screen speakers. The audio switches back to the default playback device when the second screen is disconnected.

However, there is another seemingly related audio issue that also happens randomly. The second playback device can sometimes disappear from the list of playback devices, and the default playback device receives no audio, evident by the lack of movement on the sound meter. The second playback device is stated to be in use by another application, but no sound can be heard from any source. In addition, Windows Media Player encounters a problem when this issue happens, and it does not attempt to play. The only way I have found to reverse the effects of this issue is to restart the computer.

Neither of these are hardware-related issues because the audio works fine under Ubuntu. The Windows services "Windows Audio" and "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder" are active and restarting them has no effect.The audio has worked fine for a while before the issue started occurring, but there was no major software change prior to encountering this issue.

I can post more detailed specs if they are needed.

---

Update: The problem went away as mysteriously as it appeared. I still do not know what caused it, but the issue seems to have been fixed.

Comment: What's the version of the audio driver?

Comment: The driver version is 6.0.1.6695, for Realtek High Definition Audio. I've also noticed that disabling then enabling the device temporarily solves the problem, but it's by no means a permanent fix.

Comment: That's the latest version provided by Sony. You can try using a newer version, available here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false When you're done installing it, restart Windows and see whether you're still getting the same issue.

Comment: It's been a while since I've responded, but the problem seems to have vanished. As far as I know, I didn't make any changes, so I have no way of knowing what caused the problem.